No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test11
I am creating an application using JPA-Hibernate and getting error  while executing

No Persistence provider for EntityManager named
test11"

what's the issue?
I tried to check my Persistence.xml and POM.xml class.
Everything seems fine to me.
POM.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        
         <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
          <groupId>com.faisal</groupId>
          <artifactId>JPAHIbernateApp1</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        
          <name>JPAHIbernateApp1</name>
          <!-- FIXME change it to the projects website -->
          <url>http://www.example.com</url>
          
        
          <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF- 
            8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
          </properties>
          
        
          <dependencies>
             <!-- JPA Dependencies --> 
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
              <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Hibernate Dependencies-->
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
              <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- SQL Driver Dependencies-->
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>mysql</groupId>
              <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
              <version>8.0.23</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- JAXB Dependencies-->
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
              
            <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.11</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          
        
          <build>
            <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to 
        avoid 
          using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
              <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see 
          https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven- 
           core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see 
             https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven- 
            core/default- 
             bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see 
            https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven- 
            core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports- 
            plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            
           
             </build>
          
           </project>
            

Persistence.xml:
         <persistence 
           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
            instance"
                     
            
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
            
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
                     version="2.0">
        
            <persistence-unit name="test11" transaction- 
            type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">         
 
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
                
<class>com.faisal.entity.ProductEntity</class>
        
                <properties>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
              value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/advjdb"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***"/>
                    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***"/>
        
                    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
                    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
                    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                    
                </properties>
        
            </persistence-unit>
        
        </persistence>   
            

ProductEntity Class:
package com.faisal.entity;
        
        import java.time.LocalDateTime;
        
        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.Table;
        
        import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
        import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
        
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "tbl_products")
        public class ProductEntity {
            
            @Id
            @Column(name = "product_id")
            private Integer productId;
            
            @Column(name = "product_name")
            private String productName;
            
            private Integer quantity;
        
            @Column(name = "unit_price")
            private Double unitPrice;
            
            @Column(name ="CREATED_ON")
            @CreationTimestamp
            private LocalDateTime createdOn;
            
            @Column(name = "LASTUPDATED_ON")
            @UpdateTimestamp
            private LocalDateTime updatedOn;
        
            public Integer getProductId() {
                return productId;
            }
        
            public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
                this.productId = productId;
            }
        
            public String getProductName() {
                return productName;
            }
        
            public void setProductName(String productName) {
                this.productName = productName;
            }
        
            public Integer getQuantity() {
                return quantity;
            }
        
            public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
                this.quantity = quantity;
            }
        
            public Double getUnitPrice() {
                return unitPrice;
            }
        
            public void setUnitPrice(Double unitPrice) {
                this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
            }
        
            public LocalDateTime getCreatedOn() {
                return createdOn;
            }
        
            public void setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime createdOn) {
                this.createdOn = createdOn;
            }
        
            public LocalDateTime getUpdatedOn() {
                return updatedOn;
            }
        
            public void setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime updatedOn) {
                this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
            }
        
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "ProductEntity [productId=" + productId + ", productName=" + productName + ", quantity=" + quantity
                        + ", unitPrice=" + unitPrice + ", createdOn=" + createdOn + ", updatedOn=" + updatedOn + "]";
            }
            
            
            
        }


ProductDAOImpl class:
package com.faisal.dao.impl;
        
        
        
        import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
        import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
        import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
        import javax.persistence.Persistence;
        
        
        import com.faisal.dao.ProductDAO;
        import com.faisal.entity.ProductEntity;
        
        public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO{
        
            
            
            
            private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test11");
            
            
            @Override
            public ProductEntity saveProduct(ProductEntity product) {
                EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
                EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
                transaction.begin();
                try {
                    entityManager.persist(product);
                    transaction.commit();
                    System.out.println("Data is Inserted into DB");
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                    System.out.println("Data is not inserted");
                }finally {
                    entityManager.close();
                }
                return product;
            }
        
            @Override
            public ProductEntity loadProductById(Integer productId) {
                EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
                
                /**
                 find()  early load
                 getReference lazy load
                 **/
                
                ProductEntity p = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, productId);
                
                entityManager.close();
                
                return p;
            }
        
            @Override
            public ProductEntity updateProductById(Integer productId, Double new_unitPrice) {
                EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
                EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
                ProductEntity p = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, productId);
                p.setUnitPrice(new_unitPrice);
                transaction.begin();
                try {
                    
                    entityManager.merge(p);
                    transaction.commit();
                    System.out.println("Records updated");
                    
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    transaction.rollback();
        System.out.println("Records not updated");
                }finally {
                    entityManager.close();
                }
                return p;
            }
        
            @Override
            public void delete(Integer productId) {
                EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
                EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
                ProductEntity p = entityManager.find(ProductEntity.class, productId);
                transaction.begin();
                try {
                    entityManager.remove(p);
                    transaction.commit();
                    System.out.println("Records deleted");
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                    System.out.println("Records not deleted");
                }finally {
                    entityManager.close();
                }
            }
            
            
            
        
        }

ProductDAO:

         package com.faisal.dao;
                
                import com.faisal.entity.ProductEntity;
                
                public interface ProductDAO {
                    
                    ProductEntity saveProduct(ProductEntity product);
                    ProductEntity loadProductById(Integer productId);
                    ProductEntity updateProductById(Integer productId, Double new_unitPrice);
                    void delete(Integer productId);
                }
                

Tester Class:
        package com.faisal.client;
                
                import java.time.LocalDateTime;
                
                import com.faisal.dao.ProductDAO;
                import com.faisal.dao.impl.ProductDAOImpl;
                import com.faisal.entity.ProductEntity;
                
                public class Tester {
                
                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        
                        ProductDAO dao = new ProductDAOImpl();
                        ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();
                        product.setProductId(101);
                        product.setProductName("Bag");
                        product.setQuantity(5);
                        product.setUnitPrice(200.00);
                        product.setCreatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
                        product.setUpdatedOn(LocalDateTime.now());
                        
                        dao.saveProduct(product);
                
                    }
                
                }


resolved the issue by changing org.hibernate.core version
